# How to read inner level tag from xml with minidom and python

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, python-3.5, minidom

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><cfdi:Comprobante Version="3.3" xmlns:cfdi="http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3 http://www.sat.gob.mx/sitio_internet/cfd/3/cfdv33.xsd " Serie="KNS" Folio="44" Fecha="2018-02-01T09:19:56" NoCertificado="00001000000407880000" Certificado="MIIGMzCCBBug...."" Moneda="MXN" TipoDeComprobante="I" MetodoPago="PUE" FormaPago="99" CondicionesDePago="Contado" SubTotal="540.00" Total="626.40" LugarExpedicion="11320" Sello="JKVJ""><cfdi:Emisor Rfc="GKM060127GP4" Nombre="GRUPO KROME DE MEXICO, SA DE CV" RegimenFiscal="601"/>
<cfdi:Receptor Rfc="IBS000800000" Nombre="IB Sistemas, S.A. de C.V."  UsoCFDI="G03"/>
<cfdi:Conceptos><cfdi:Concepto ClaveProdServ="82101500" Cantidad="2.00" ClaveUnidad="HC" Descripcion="Tarjetas de presentación, impresas en offset digital." ValorUnitario="270.00" Importe="540.00"><cfdi:Impuestos><cfdi:Traslados><cfdi:Traslado Base="540.00" Impuesto="002" TipoFactor="Tasa" TasaOCuota="0.160000" Importe="86.40"/></cfdi:Traslados></cfdi:Impuestos></cfdi:Concepto></cfdi:Conceptos><cfdi:Impuestos TotalImpuestosTrasladados="86.40"> <cfdi:Traslados><cfdi:Traslado Impuesto="002" TipoFactor="Tasa" TasaOCuota="0.160000"  Importe="86.40"/></cfdi:Traslados> </cfdi:Impuestos><cfdi:Complemento><tfd:TimbreFiscalDigital xmlns:tfd="http://www.sat.gob.mx/TimbreFiscalDigital" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sat.gob.mx/TimbreFiscalDigital http://www.sat.gob.mx/sitio_internet/cfd/TimbreFiscalDigital/TimbreFiscalDigitalv11.xsd" Version="1.1" UUID="5CA56521-0763-11E8-87CC-00155D014007" FechaTimbrado="2018-02-01T09:19:57" RfcProvCertif="TBN040609RKA" SelloCFD="JKVJ"" NoCertificadoSAT="00001000000403557578" SelloSAT="jXmC54X9fW""/></cfdi:Complemento></cfdi:Comprobante>
```

I have an xml file (This schema is used in the Mexican Tributary System - SAT to create and manage invoices) with the following structure:

From which I want to obtain certain data. 
I am using python 3.5 and minidom
I have managed to obtain most of the data but I have not been able to get the data of the "totalImpuestosTrasladados" field.

I don´t know why the "getElementsByTagName" works for some fields but not for this one

Any help is really appreciated

Answer (score 0):

As I can see, you have `namespaces` in the aforementioned XML. In order to get the Elements using tag names you'll have to use `getElementsByTagNameNS(namespace, tag)` with the appropriate namespaces and you'll get the correct search result.

You can read more about it on [Element namespace search](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.dom.html#xml.dom.Element.getElementsByTagNameNS)